# why does writing the simplest code in html on Chrome not work

Tags: javascript, html

such as just:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example of confirm()</title>
        <script>
           if (confirm("Want to go to Disneyland?"))
           document.location.href
           =“http://park.hongkongdisneyland.com”;
       </script>             //says this wont work, because of the /<
    </head>               //says this wont work, because of the /<
</html>              //says this wont work, because of the /<
```

**VM43:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

Comment: That code is correct. Probably the error is somewhere else.

Comment: This question is difficult to interpret, but I'm assuming your HTML is invalid. Please post your HTML code if you want any useful feedback.

Comment: Also use "code blocks" to post code otherwise it's really unreadable.

Comment: Try using regular quotes instead of curly quotes.

Comment: Your quotes are jacked up.  Use `"`, not `“` and `”`.

Answer (score 0):

As cHao stated, you got to make sure you using the right "

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example of confirm()</title>
        <script>
           if (confirm("Want to go to Disneyland?"))
           document.location.href
           ="http://park.hongkongdisneyland.com"; //This was changed
       </script>
    </head>
</html>
```